# what does "a real articulate fella." means?

Tags: meaning

I don't get understand the meaning of this sentence please help me. It seems to call for cultural knowledge that I don't have. 
this sentence is for zootopia animation.

> I just wanna say you're a great dad and just **a real articulate fella**.

What does **a real articulate fella** mean?

Comment: It probably just means "an all-round good guy." (fella = fellow)

Comment: The word *real* can be used as an intensifier in some varieties of English, in the same way that the word *really* is used in standard Englishes. So *He's real articulate* can mean *He's really articulate*.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't feel research would cut it here. It is not about individual words. It's about the style and if an OP can't identify that, the OP needs help. And in my book and it can only come from those who understand it. This is not an ELL question. It's a literary one, in fact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Humorous writing:
Zootopia: "I just wanna say you're a great dad and just a real articulate fella."

Register: Informal speech

Evidence of informal speech: 1) the use of wanna instead of want to, 2) the use of real as an adverb (instead of really) 3) fella as opposed to fellow. Fella is marked in American English as southern, western or mid-western

Juxtaposition: Informal register speech with a rather formal word: articulate, which means well spoken and/or who expresses himself well.

Conclusion: using the word articulate in the context of what is, overall, informal speech produces a comic effect.

Answer (score 0):

*Real*: deserving the name; rightly so called (Collins English Dictionary)

*Articulate*: able to express oneself fluently and coherently (CED again)

*Fella*: (informal) a man (Cambridge Dictionary)